# Angular - Dropdown list optimization

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-ngfor

I have a drop down list and it's corresponding sub dropdown lists created by two *ngFors. Clicking on the main drop down list item toggles the display of its child/sub dropdown list, and clicking on the child list toggles it's content.
The problem is the main list could have upto 20 items and the child lists around 1-500 items. this makes the UI very slow and unresponsive.

Is there a better way to do this? It looks like angular recreates the list each time the on click event happens.

```
<ul *ngfor = "let x of variable">
   <li> 
       <span (click) = "hideSudlist()"> {{x}} </span>
        //sub list
         <ul *ngfor let y of variable *ngIf=mainListHasBeenClicked()>
            <li (click) = hideChildDiv()>
               {{y}}
                <div> child content </div>
             </li>
          </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I will recommend to use angular-virtual-CDK for scorlling and displaying large data list : 
You can check this blog maybe it helps https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-ways-to-render-large-lists-in-angular-9f4dcb9b65?gi=34527fa2598

Comment: On click on parent are you showing children only for clicked parent item or for all parent items ?

Comment: in a *ngIF, use a variable, not a function. When you use a variable (if only show one sublist at time you only need one variable, else you need an array or if your "variable" is an array of object a new property in each element of the array). When you use *ngIf="variable" Angular check if the variable change, if you use *ngIf="myfunction()" Angular need execute myfunction to know is there're a change or not. You can use also trackBy in the *ngFor, see e.g. this [link](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)